# Stream using html5 <video> tag (Page load time fix)

Tags: html, html5-video

I'm not sure how to use the html5 `video` tag. Right now, i'm using as the following :

```
<video class="hero-media-container__item" playsinline="playsinline" autoplay="autoplay" muted="muted" loop="loop">
  <source src="https://player.vimeo.com/external/xxXXxx.hd.mp4?s=XXXc&profile_id=XXX" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

My issue is that it make my page load ultra slowly ! My question is the following :
How can i -stream- the video, rather than downloading it on the page load ?

Comment: It *is* streaming it.  You're autoplaying a video.  Yes, that will have contention for bandwidth from other things.  Ideally, use HLS or DASH which support bitrate changes based on bandwidth availability.

Comment: Hi @Brad thanks you for your answer ! I'm not sure to understand your answer ( meaning how to use the HLS or DASH part ... ). How can i achieve this ?

Comment: Since you're already using Vimeo, easiest thing would be to use their embedded player.  It will take care of all of this for you.